# Open CV - Removing a colored region from an image

Tags: java, image, opencv

I am trying to remove a particular color( Grey in this case ) from an image using OpenCV & Java.
I want all the other parts of the image should be present in the output image

Here is what I have tried.

```
     System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
     Mat original = Imgcodecs.imread("C:\\ABC\\App2.jpg");
     
     Mat dst = new Mat();
     Core.inRange(original, new Scalar( 88, 88, 88), new Scalar( 88, 88, 88), dst);
     Imgcodecs.imwrite("C:\\ABC\\mask4.jpg", dst);
```

Original Image: https://freeimage.host/i/dkdqXe
Original Output: https://freeimage.host/i/dkdukB

What it does is, the grey colored portion of the image is shown in white and the rest of the image is all black. But I just want to remove ( or make transparent ) the grey colored portion from the original image without affecting the other parts of the image. Any help pr input is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Python you define the area by giving the range of the points:

```
import cv2
img=cv2.imread('test.jpg', -1)
crop_img = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
cv2.imshow("cropped", crop_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Hope that can help you figuring in out in Java respectivly.

UPDATE #2

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('lena.jpg', -1)
roi = cv2.selectROI(img, False)
crop_img = img[roi[1]:(roi[1]+roi[3]), roi[0]:(roi[0]+roi[2])]
cv2.imwrite('cropped',crop_img)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. Is there any other option to remove the selected portion without mentioning the co-ordinates?

Comment: i dont think so. But you can simplify it by defining a Region of Interest (ROI) with your mouse and crop it like that. see Update #2